# Зачем использовать реализацию базового метода в методе override?

Tags: c#, методы, override

Книга ***Джон Шарп - Microsoft Visual C#. Подробное руководство - 2017***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем так делать, если мы можем просто не определять этот метод в наследнике и он по умолчанию вызовет метод базового класса?

Comment: а если надо что-то добавить к тому что вернет базовая версия или обработать как-то особенно?

Comment: @Grundy вы правы, как-то я упустил этот момент из головы)